# Building comment tree efficiently in Metro XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to build a 'comments control' (In a win8 XAML app, which is similar to Silverlight) which will load and render a comment tree for the user.

Each comment can have 0 or 1+ children comments (which recurses through each comment).

Each comment displays a set of info, including author, time, the comment itself, etc.

The approach I initially took to build this is to use a ListView which has a 'CommentItem' control binding.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding commentText}" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="CommentRepliesList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:CommentItem Tag="{Binding}"></local:CommentItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The above will just recurse through each comment, apply the comment text, and then create a new commentitem for each comment child, recurse through again, etc.

The issue, however, is this is extremely slow and non-performant.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this? Is ListView the appropriate control to use for this?

Comment: it sounds you want a treeview with hierarchicaldatatemplates, they are built for recursive controls

Comment: Are either of those available in Metro apps? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: wow... you're right, i cant believe such a standard control doesn't exist, maybe this helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/c37ea9bf-c5a6-4f87-8032-91bcaa2c9e45